# hadoop 2 node cluster setup

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

Can anyone please tell how to create a hadoop 2 node cluster ?i have 2 Virual machines both have hadoop single node setup installed properly,please tell how to form 2 node cluster from that ,and mention proper network setup for that.Thanks in Advance.i am using hadoop -1.0.3 version.

Answer (score 0):

Hi can you do one thing for network configuration of vms.
Make sure of the network connect of virtual machine setting of hostonly.
And add two hostname and ips in /etc/hosts file.
add two hostnames in $HADOOP_HOME/conf/slaves file.
Make sure of secondary namenode hostname in $HADOOP_HOME/conf/masters file.
Then make sure same configuration on two machine.

hadoop namenode -format

start-all.sh

Best of luck.